# Swift: How to bitwise OR two things that were enum constants in C?

Tags: c, swift, enums

## Setup

OS X 10.10.2
Xcode 6.1

## Question

This is a dumb Swift syntax question. In Swift, how do you bitwise OR two things (I gather they are `Int`s in Swift) that were enum integer constants in C?

Specifically, here's an example of what I'm trying to do would look like in C:

```
CGGradientDrawingOptions opts = kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation|kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation;
```

When I try this in Swift:

```
let options: CGGradientDrawingOptions = kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation|kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation;
```

I get this compile-time error:

```
Cannot invoke '|' with an argument list of type '(Int, Int)'
```

What is my syntax error here? I have tried many obvious variations including lots of different `as` casts, inclusion and exclusion of the specific `CGGradientDrawingOptions` type decl, but I cannot find the correct syntax for this very simple operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation` and `kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation` is `Int`, whereas `CGGradientDrawingOptions` is alias of `UInt32`

You have to convert `Int` to `UInt32`:

```
let options: CGGradientDrawingOptions = UInt32(kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation|kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation)
```

But the following is better I think.

```
let options = CGGradientDrawingOptions(kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation|kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation)
```

---

**ADDED:** As for Xcode7/Swift2.0:

```
let options: CGGradientDrawingOptions = [.DrawsBeforeStartLocation, .DrawsAfterEndLocation]
```

Comment: Perfect. Works. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: How would look this answer in Swift 2? A compiler does not recognize kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation. Thanks